# Trying to combine two Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to combine two working regex patterns into one. Please let me know the correct syntax and if this can be better written.

```
Pattern 1: (?P<date>.*)\s+(?P<timezone>.*)\|.*\|.*\|(?P<ip>[\w*.:-]+)\|.*\|
Pattern 2: (?P<path>[^\/]+(?=\-[^\/-]*$))
```

Sample line:

```
06/Mar/2020:00:01:04 -0500|/TESTSTREAM|5766764|4.2.2.1|123290|path1/path2/x-fr-US.OPEN.1-Turtle-2020.30.04-64.mp3
```

Comment: Is that using PCRE, or Perl regexes, or something else?

Comment: Assuming Perl-ish regexes, you should not be using greedy matches (`.*`).  They will consume too much information, in general.  Consider `[^|]*\|` to match anything that isn't a pipe symbol followed by a pipe — and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first expression matches the start of the string, the second matches the end, you can combine them by putting a non-greedy `.*?` between them, like this:

```
(?P<date>.*)\s+(?P<timezone>.*)\|.*\|.*\|(?P<ip>[\w*.:-]+)\|.*\|.*?(?P<path>[^\/]+(?=\-[^\/-]*$))
```

As you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/DgaiaH/1) this expression works, but it takes 1660 steps to match the string. This is because `.*` between `|` first capture the whole string up to the end, and then try to step back character by character in order to find the match.

If you use the non-greedy modifiers here: `.*?`, then the regex machine will initially match an empty string and then will need to move forward character by character until it finds the matching `|`. It will reduce the number of steps to 1183: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DgaiaH/2)

However, if you want to remove this backtracking (forward-tracking) at all, you can just very quickly skip as many non-`|` characters as possible with `[^|]*`. Similarly we can replace other `.*` patterns in the regex. The resulting regex finds a match in just 47 steps, more than 30-times less than the original regex:

```
(?P<date>\S*)\s+(?P<timezone>[^|]*)\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|(?P<ip>[\w*.:-]+)\|[^|]*\|(?:[^\/\n]*\/)*(?P<path>.*)-.*
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/DgaiaH/6).

**Update 2020-03-09**

If you want to keep the last slash you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/DgaiaH/7):

```
(?P<date>\S*)\s+(?P<timezone>[^|]*)\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|(?P<ip>[\w*.:-]+)\|[^|]*\|.*?(?P<path>\/[^\/]*)-[^\/]*
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the last slash before the path?

Comment: Update answer to include the last slash. You might also consider just adding a slash to your path variable manually, something like `$path = "/" . $path`.